# Vuefire - get key within v-for loop

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, vue.js, vuefire

I'm new to Vue and Vuefire. I am trying to create a dynamic link to a page using the key as the URL ID.

My reference is set up as

```
let db = app.database();
const postsRef = db.ref('posts');
```

and I'm importing the global refs into my app page like so -

```
firebase: {
  posts: {
    source: postsRef,
    asObject: true,
    readyCallback: function () {
      console.log(postsRef)
    }
  },
},
```

and iterating over the posts object like so -

```
<div v-for="post in posts">
  <a :href="'post/' + post.key"></a>
</div>
```

My database is structured like so - 
[DB Structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VAkdz.png)

What would be the best way to use the key considering that I might want to retrieve at the posts page, preferably without using URL Params? When I log the postsRef object, I see that the parent value is null and the key value is posts. I want the key value to retrieve the unique ID of the element in the for loop.

Comment: I'm also looking for a solution this :/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So basically, removing the asObject: true and importing it as an array instead works for me. In my case, the key can be accessed as

```
post['.key']
```